# checking strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to see if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array.

For example

```
['hello', 'hey'] = false;
['Army', 'Mary'] = true;
```

Here is my code

```
function mutation(arr) {
  a = arr[0].toLowerCase().split("");
  b = arr[1].toLowerCase().split("");
  for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if(b.indexOf(a[i]) != -1){
      console.log('true');
    } else {
      console.log('false');
    }
  }
}
mutation(['Army', 'Mary']);
```

***UPDATED***

I need to see if element 1 contains all the letters for element 2 before I return back anything.

Comment: Good, but what help you need from us ?? Whats question

Comment: @Panther i updated my question, I left out a crucial part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need to loop throught the second element letters and return `false` if a character doesn't exist in first element, or `continue` the loop if it exists.

Then check if the counter is equal to your string length then it contains all the given letters and return true:

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  a = arr[1].toLowerCase().split("");
  b = arr[0].toLowerCase().split("");
  if (a === b) return true;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (i === a.length) {
    return true; // all the letteers of element one exists in the second element
  }
}

if (mutation(['Army', 'Mary'])) {
  alert("Element one contains all letters of second element !");
} else {
  alert("Sorry!");
}
```

**Note:**

Make sure you loop throught the second element characters and not the first one, see the `a = arr[1].toLowerCase().split("");`.

Comment: since i did `!= -1` shouldn't the results be the same tho?

Comment: No you need to test if it's `=== -1` so this character doesn't exist in that case you just need to break the loop and return `false`, if you test `!= -1` then itt's found and you need to continue the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This would do, I'm sure there are better and optimal solutions though,

1) Storing the return result in a boolean, as `var result = true;`.

2) Check if both the Strings are equal/same, no need to loop, return the `result` which is true.

3) loop through each characters and see if the target element contains them, if   found a mismatch set, `result` to false, `break` and return `result`.

```
function mutation(arr) {
a = arr[0].toLowerCase().split("");
b = arr[1].toLowerCase().split("");
var result = true;
if(a === b)
return result;
  for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if(b.indexOf(a[i]) === -1){
      result = false;
      break;
    } 
  }
return result;
}
mutation(['Army', 'Mary']);
```

**UPDATE** Added a condition if `(a === b) return true;` to skip for loop.

Answer (score 2):

No need of *loop*, you can take advantage of `array` functions.

**Steps**

1. `Sort` both arrays
2. Cast to the string
3. Check if strings2 contains string1

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  var a = arr[0].toLowerCase().split(''),
    b = arr[1].toLowerCase().split('');

  // For exact equality
  return a.sort().toString() === b.sort().toString();

  // return b.sort().toString().indexOf(a.sort().toString()) > -1;
}

document.write('Army and Mary: ' + mutation(['Army', 'Mary'])); // true

document.write('<br />a and b: ' + mutation(['a', 'b'])); // false

document.write('<br />ab and abc: ' + mutation(['ab', 'abc'])); // false
```

Comment: mutation(['ab', 'abc']); should be true since the first element contains all the letters of the second element don't think this is what he wanted

Comment: @herriekrekel No this should be false because `c` doesn't exist in the first element, we are checking all letters in the second element here, you are mixing up things :)

Comment: `mutation(['ab', 'abc'])` should return `false` because we are testinf if **the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array** and `c`in second element isn't in the first, but nice approach man.

Answer (score 0):

```
  //mutation function work ignoring case and order of character in strings
  function mutation(arr) {
  var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
   var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();
    for(var i = 0; i < second.length; i++){
   if(first.indexOf(second[i]) == -1){
       return false;
  }
  }
  return true;
  }
  //this returns true
  mutation(["hello", "ol"]);
```